# Use relative url with file function in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using PHP to display the first line of a 'current score' text file.  The text file is update every minute via cron.  This works great... however I want to use relative URL, not absolute/

If I change http://example.com/data/currentscore.txt to /data/currentscore.txt, the script no longer works. The reason I want to use relative URL's is because when I have cloudflare protection enabled, the php script is blocked from pulling the data from http://example.com/data/currentscore.txt.

Here is my code.  I appreciate your help.  Thank you.

```
<?php
$myFile = "http://example.com/data/currentscore.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
echo $lines[0]; //displays line after line 0 ?>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting and use a (full) server path, not a relative one. `/data/currentscore.txt` isn't a full server path.

Comment: what is the relation between you working directory(that has the above php file) and the directory having the currentscore.txt?

Comment: _“The reason I want to use relative URL's is because when I have cloudflare protection enabled, […]”_ - nothing would change regarding that, if you switched to using a relative _URL_ (that would have to be expanded to an absolute one anyway, before the request can be made) - you want to switch to a _file system path_ instead. (Whether that one is absolute or relative, does not matter in this regard either.) Make yourself aware of why this is an important distinction first of all.

Comment: @misorude i read your comment and thought perhaps you were hinting at using something like /var/www/html/files/currentscore.txt  ........  I tried that and it worked so far for everything I wanted it to.

it is working, but did I understand you correct?    I'm definently new with unix/nginx/php.   Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The main difference is whether you make an HTTP request by using a URL (which will go through all checks and restrictions applied to normal clients/browsers as well), or directly read the data from the local file system (so that HTTP isn’t even involved any more, so all CF blocking stuff does not apply either.)